# Socket.io app ... should I use emit or use a regular http request and handle it with express?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am creating Socket.io app that at times needs to retrieve information from a database. I am having a hard time figuring out if those requests should be sent and processed using socket.io, or if they should be sent like a regular http request and processed in the server using Express.

I could use socket.emit("my-event) and then process it in the server using `socket.on("my-event", () =>{... make request to the database...})` and then upon getting the results from the database I can emit another event to send the results to the client using `socket.emit("result-from-the-DB", dataFromDB)`.

I know you may be thinking "You do not need Socket.io for that", but the most important part of the app will need it since it will function very much like a Chat app. For instance, let's say a user clicks on "See my profile" in this app. Should the request to the server be sent using socket.io (using the steps described above) or just a regular http request?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Socket.io app … should I use emit or use a regular http request and handle it with express?

There's no totally correct answer.  Honestly, you can make it work fine either way.  Here are some advantages of each:

**Advantages of sending via an http request:**

1. http is a request/response protocol.  If you're sending a request and expecting a response to a specific request, then http is a bit better designed for that.  socket.io doesn't really have a "response" to a specific "request".  You can mimic that by sending back a message or using the confirmation callback.
2. If you envision any other public use for this API/functionality or any use outside of a socket.io app, then http is more often the appropriate public API.
3. If you ever have to send large amounts of data (like uploading files), then there are more mature solutions already built for http.
4. socket.io error handling is more at the global level, rather than for a specific message.  For example, there's no way to listen specifically whether there was an error on sending a particular message.  If the socket.io library encounters a socket problem, it will close the socket and attempt to reconnect.  Sometimes this is a feature, sometimes this is an obstacle to knowing if your data actually got there or not.  An http request will give you clear and direct feedback whether your request was delivered or not.
5. If what you're doing in processing this message has nothing to do with the other things you're doing with socket.io, then it may be cleaner (from a module design point of view) to handle it with http so you don't have to mix in code in your socket.io module that isn't related to the other stuff.

**Advantages of sending via a socket.io message:**

1. Once you already have a socket.io connection active, it's much lower overhead to send a small message to your server using socket.io.  so, particularly if you were sending lots of small messages this way, socket.io could be significantly more efficient.
2. If there's any benefit to socket.io features such as namespaces and rooms in processing this request, then it may be easier to handle it on the server with socket.io.
3. If the message you're sending is directly related to the other things you've doing with socket.io on the server, then it may be cleaner (from a module design point of view) to handle that request in your socket.io module.